# NEW.value IS DISTINCT FROM OLD.value seems to have no effect (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, insert, distinct

I have a first table(A) with a date field(d) and a bool field(b). Everytime d is updated, it triggers an insert in a second table(B) with the function:

```
BEGIN 

    INSERT INTO B(field)
    SELECT d
    FROM A
    WHERE b IS true AND OLD.d IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.d;

    RETURN NEW;

END
```

I want it to insert an element containing d in B, only if b is true and d was just updated,but everytime the function gets triggered, every date with b being true gets inserted in B, regardless of if d was changed or not.

The trigger is a row trigger, which fires AFTER an update of d.

I guess I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you want something like this:

```
INSERT INTO B (field)
    SELECT d
    FROM (SELECT new.d as d) n
    WHERE new.b IS true AND OLD.d IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.d;
```

I don't see why you would want to insert (potentially) all rows from `a`.

Comment: It worked! I still don't get why all rows with b true were inserted if I updated only one date, and I didn't know FROM(SELECT) was a thing (still new to SQL in general). Thank you for the quick answer!

Comment: @GabStPier . . . You have `from a` in your version.  That selects all rows from `a` (subject to the filtering conditions, of course).